# How to recursively apply command

Tags: bash, video, directory, subdirectory

I'm still a newbie in `bash` and I'm trying to create a `bash` script in order to transcribe all the videos and audio files I have. Any file extension.
So far I can transcribe all the video files from the same folder I run the `bash` script.

For example. The command below allows me to transcribe all the video files in the same folder where the bash script is located.

```
for file in *
do
  autosub -S de -D de "$file" >> results.out
done
```

I'm trying to make the same command recursively so I don't have to do it on each folder each time.

```
for file in \*
do
  autosub -S de -D de "$file" >> results.out
done
```

So I've changed it a bit the command above and it still doesn't work. It tries to apply the command recursively but to `folders` instead of `files`. It only applies the command to files when it's located inside the same folder as the bash script.

What I'm trying to achieve is:
Run a command with `autosub -S de -D de $file` for every file (any extension. If it can't be transcribed, it will skip automatically. You don't have to write that in the bash script since `autosub` already skips)

I want to transcribe all the video files inside a folder structure like that:

```
Folder 1
------SubFolder 2
----------------SubFolder 3\video.avi
Folder 2\video.mp4
Folder 1
--------SubFolder\video.mkv
```

Comment: Thanks Mr. jkdev for correcting my writing :) I'm not good at English.

Comment: Hey, @G.L, any luck with the answer below?

Comment: Hi. It works flawlessly. I even use it with Cron now. /o/

Comment: That's great news, I'm glad it worked for you! Since you're new to StackOverflow (welcome!), please note you can [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the answer that helped you. That will close the question and help users with similar questions when searching for answers.

Comment: The Accept button wasn't working for me due to a browser plugin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically, one would use [`find`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) for this:

```
find . -type f -execdir autosub -S de -D de {} \; >> results.out
```

This will execute your command for every *file* (notice: `-type f`) located below your current directory (notice `.`). The command is executed each time inside the directory the file is in (notice: `-execdir`). That means your command will receive filenames like `./video.avi`, `./video.mp4`, and not the complete path relative to your initial directory. This is considered safer than `-exec`. All results are appended to *one file*, `./results.out`.

---

Alternatively, **if you're using `bash >= 4.0`**, you can enable [`globstar`](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/internals/shell_options#globstar) with:

```
shopt -s globstar
```

and then use [`**`](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/globs#customization) which expands recursively:

```
for file in **
do
    autosub -S de -D de "$file" >> results.out
done
```

Comment: I'd rearrange that `find` command a little -- putting `>> results.out` before `\;` seems to imply that it's part of the command that'll be executed in the file's directory, but it's actually parsed & applied by the shell before `find` even starts. Putting it at the end of the command would make this clearer.

Comment: @GordonDavisson, I completely agree. Thanks for pointing that out.